# Efficient way to compute unique permutations with restrictions

Tags: c++, permutation, restriction

so I know that there are a lot of ways to compute unique permutations.
Usually it is slower to apply restrictions during the generation than removing them afterwards.
So let's say I have a vector of 10 elements.
For the sake of an example:

```
std::vector<int> v = {7, 5, 16, 8, 5, 8, 1, 7, 3, 25, 109, 8};
```

I have the unique restriction that I know that I am not allowed to have the same three numbers in a row, so all permutations containing {8,8,8} in any place would be invalid.
In case I have a giant array of e.g. 20 elements I would assume that I could save a lot of time if I skip all permutations that start with {8,8,8}.

Is there any to do anything like this efficiently? How do I figure out at which point it makes sense to add the additional slowdown of checking each permutation?

Comment: you may be able to remove any tripled values

Comment: @ti7 Not sure what you mean by that. How would you incorporate that in permutation generation code which does not simply loop over each permutation and then checks the result for validity? I.e. if there's 100k permutations, but 80k of those are "invalid", how do you not generate those 80k at all?

Comment: Are you trying to count the permutations, or actually list them (generate them)?

Comment: And if you have 20 elements, you've got about a quintillion permutations to generate.  You either a) won't have enough storage to generate them, or b) won't have enough time to generate them. Well, maybe you will: 1 nanosecond each, that's like 70+ years.

Comment: You know that "Usually it is slower to apply restrictions during the generation than removing them afterwards." but you ask immediatly "could (I) save a lot of time if I skip all permutations that start with {8,8,8}." What makes you think that this is a special case?

Comment: The type is always int and the values are between what?

Comment: Is there only one group of 3, can there be groups of more than 3?

Comment: For most of the applications, a paticular permutation set is picked up by random numbers. The restrictions are then used to valid or invalid this particular set (for the follwoing methods). The lsit of all permutation sets for large number is not feasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your restriction, while iterating in order, it is possible to skip the block of invalid permutations, from the first invalid one.

The first invalid permutation from number of the form

`y y y 8 8 x x 8 x`

is

`y y y 8 8 8 x1 x2 x3` with x1 < x2 < x3.

so you can go directly to last invalid permutation with

`y y y 8 8 8 x3 x2 x1` with x1 < x2 < x3.

so just reverse the last numbers.

```
bool is_valid(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
    auto it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), 8);
    
    return v.end() - it >= 3 && (*it != *(it + 1) || *it != *(it + 2));
}

void go_to_last_invalid(std::vector<int>& v)
{
    auto it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), 8);
    std::reverse(it + 3, v.end());
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10};
    do {
        if (!is_valid(v)) { go_to_last_invalid(v); continue; }
        for (auto e : v) { std::cout << e << " "; } std::cout << std::endl;
    } while (std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/946a5dd366ff9f12)